# How to correctly return pointer from function

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, return

I have the following function:

```
std::wstring GetNetStatus()
{
    NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS bufType;
    ::ZeroMemory(&bufType, sizeof(NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS));

    LPWSTR buf;
    CHECK_OS_ERROR(::NetGetJoinInformation(nullptr, &buf, &bufType) == NERR_Success);

    std::wstring group(buf);
    ::NetApiBufferFree(buf);

    return group;
}
```

I need to return an `LPWSTR` value but according to the API I'm using, I need to free this pointer before I leave the function scope.

Is it correct to assign an `LPWSTR` value to the STL string and return it or are there some other tricks?

Comment: This constructor `std::wstring group(buf);` copies the characters pointed to by `buf` into the newly created `group`.  `buf` can now be safely freed.

Comment: I've never used this API before, but at a quick glance this looks correct to me. Just keep in mind that the constructor you're using of `wstring` assumes that `buf` is a null-terminated string. If `buf` is not null-terminated, then you may need to provide the size as a constructor argument. Otherwise this looks correct!

Comment: @Bitwize: since `NetGetJoinInformation()` dynamically allocates an output string and does not return how much memory was actually allocated for it, the string HAS to be null-terminated otherwise the caller could never use it safely.

Comment: why not direct return `buf` as is ? an better of course return it via parameter `PWSTR*` and function itself return error code

Comment: @RbMm: returning `buf` directly to the caller would require the caller to take ownership of the memory and call `NetApiBufferFree()` when done using it. And that is assuming the caller even knows that `GetNetStatus()` internally uses an API that returns a pointer that needs to be freed using `NetApiBufferFree()` and not `free()` or `delete[]` or `LocalFree()` or anything like that.  Returning a `std::wstring` is safer, and more C++-ish anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - if caller call some function - it must know what this function do, how need free resources allocated inside this function. this will be the same agreement like for `NetGetJoinInformation` - need call `NetApiBufferFree` for free buffer. this already question of style. but i never can understand for what need allocate additional buffer, copy data to it and free initial. and `std::wstring` also use some free routine. what be if we call this function from another module, which bind to another crt ? are this like call *new* in one module and *delete* from another

Comment: @RbMm: "*if caller call some function - it must know what this function do*" - no, it only needs to know what the input is and what the output is, not what the function does internally. "*how need free resources allocated inside this function*" - only resources that are returned to the caller. "*but i never can understand for what need allocate additional buffer, copy data to it and free initial*" - it makes the data safer to work with, and hides details about the internal API, in case it has to be changed at a later time without changing the function's interface.

Comment: `NetGetJoinInformation` has C-interface. If you don't want to do the copy, then return some other smart pointer. `std::unique_ptr` for example.

Comment: @RbMm: "*what be if we call this function from another module, which bind to another crt ?*" - you can't safely pass class objects across module boundaries, for exactly that reason.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - in `NetGetJoinInformation` description said that need use  `NetApiBufferFree` for free buffer. so exactly this note need and for `GetNetStatus`. this i mean. and this work across different modules, unlike `std::wstring`. as result i think that use `NetApiBufferFree` as free routine and not do additional allocation and copy much more better compare `wstring`

Comment: @RbMm: If `GetNetStatus()` doesn't return `LPWSTR`, the caller of `GetNetStatus()` doesn't need to know that `NetGetJoinInformation()` is used. Suppose someday `GetNetStatus()` wants to use a different API that fills a pre-allocated `WCHAR[]` buffer. If `GetNetStatus()` returned `LPWSTR`, it would have to allocate a local buffer with `NetApiBufferAllocate()` to not break older callers, defeating any benefit that the newer API might offer. Using `std::wstring`, `GetNetStatus()` can use whatever API it wants, change over time, and the details are hidden from callers. This is "better" API design.

Comment: @RbMm: And you are arguing that `GetNetStatus()` can be called over module boundaries to begin with, which is not likely to happen given the OP's original code.  If you want to write code that follows C semantics instead of C++ semantics, go right ahead.  Most C++ developers actually want to write C++ code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - not view any problem for call `NetApiBufferAllocate` for allocate memory direct if need. this is anyway better than call some crt allocator (because exists different crts, and different modules can use different, when `NetApiBufferAllocate` only one). and how i say at begin - this is personal choice and style - what to use

Comment: @RbMm: *Assume* a newer API is added in the future, and `GetNetStatus()` wants to use it.  Returning `std::wstring` could look like this: `std::wstring GetNetStatus() { WCHAR buf[MAX_SIZE]; DWORD size; CHECK_OS_ERROR(::NetGetJoinInformation2(nullptr, buf, MAX_SIZE, &size, &bufType) == NERR_Success); return std::wstring(buf, size); }` This change in API doesn't break any existing callers who only knew about `std::wstring` and nothing about `NetGetJoinInformation()` or `NetApiBufferFree()`.

Comment: @RbMm: If `GetNetStatus()` returned `LPWSTR`, changing the API would require logic like this to maintain backwards compatibility with callers who call `NetApiBufferFree()` directly: `LPWSTR GetNetStatus() { LPWSTR buf; DWORD size; NET_API_STATUS err = NetApiBufferAllocate((MAX_SIZE+1)*sizeof(WCHAR), (void**)&buf); CHECK_OS_ERROR(err == NERR_Success); err = ::NetGetJoinInformation2(nullptr, buf, MAX_SIZE, &size, &bufType); if (err != NERR_Success) { ::NetApiBufferFree(buf); CHECK_OS_ERROR(false); } buf[size] = 0; return buf; }`

Comment: @RbMm: Besides, the use of `CHECK_OS_ERROR()` implies an exception is raised if something goees wrong, and that doesn't work across module boundaries anyway, so returning `std::wstring` is safe.  Returning `LPWSTR` is more work for everyone, and is more prone to error.  Using `std::wstring` is safer and less work for everyone.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - i supporter of nt style coding. all functions must return error code (or void). and `PWSTR` return not direct by via out parameter - exactly as `NetGetJoinInformation` do this. and not raise exception from function. but everybody can decide yourself how do coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is technically correct.

However, just be aware that when the `std::wstring` copies the character data from `buf`, it has the *potential* to throw an exception, so you should be prepared to handle that to avoid any possible memory leak.

You could use a `__try/__finally`:

```
std::wstring GetNetStatus()
{
    std::wstring result;

    NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS bufType;
    ::ZeroMemory(&bufType, sizeof(NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS));

    LPWSTR buf;
    CHECK_OS_ERROR(::NetGetJoinInformation(nullptr, &buf, &bufType) == NERR_Success);

    try {
        result = buf;
    }
    __finally {
        ::NetApiBufferFree(buf);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Or, you could write a custom `class`/`struct` that follows RAII semantics:

```
template <typename T>
class NetApiBuffer
{
private:
    T* m_buf;

    NetApiBuffer(const NetApiBuffer &) {}
    NetApiBuffer& operator=(const NetApiBuffer &) { return *this; }

public:    
    NetApiBuffer(T *buf = 0) : m_buf(buf) {}

    ~NetApiBuffer() {
        ::NetApiBufferFree(m_buf);
    }

    operator T*() { return m_buf; }
    T** operator&() { return &m_buf; }
};

std::wstring GetNetStatus()
{
    NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS bufType;
    ::ZeroMemory(&bufType, sizeof(NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS));

    NetApiBuffer<WCHAR> buf;
    CHECK_OS_ERROR(::NetGetJoinInformation(nullptr, &buf, &bufType) == NERR_Success);

    return std::wstring(buf);
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later, you can use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
std::wstring GetNetStatus()
{
    NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS bufType;
    ::ZeroMemory(&bufType, sizeof(NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS));

    LPWSTR buf;
    CHECK_OS_ERROR(::NetGetJoinInformation(nullptr, &buf, &bufType) == NERR_Success);

    std::unique_ptr<WCHAR, decltype(&::NetApiBufferFree)> deleter(buf, &::NetApiBufferFree);
    return std::wstring(buf);
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, isn't there a standard/common class which already does what your `NetApiBuffer` does? Since the functionality is pretty generic?

Comment: @Jarod42: look again more carefully at my `std::unique_ptr` example. `buf` is the raw `wchar_t*` pointer, `deleter` is the `std::unique_ptr` object.  What you would say is true if I were passing the `std::unique_ptr` object to the `std::wstring` constructor, but I'm not.

Comment: @Lou: No, there is no *standard* class for this. `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter comes close, but it doesn't implement `operator&` to get the address of the data pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you build a `std::wstring` with that raw C-style string pointer, the `wstring` object *deep-copies* the string pointed by the input raw pointer, so you are safe to return the `wstring` object back to the caller.

What you could do to improve your code quality is replacing the *explicit* string memory release call to `NetApiBufferFree` with a safe RAII wrapper, for example using `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter, e.g.:

```
// LPWSTR buf;
// ... 
//  
// ::NetApiBufferFree(buf);

auto deleter = [](void* ptr) { ::NetApiBufferFree(ptr); };
std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(deleter)> autoDelete(buf, deleter);
```

Your whole function code can be adjusted like this:

```
std::wstring GetNetStatus() 
{
    NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS bufType;
    ::ZeroMemory(&bufType, sizeof(NETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS));

    LPWSTR buf = nullptr;
    CHECK_OS_ERROR(::NetGetJoinInformation(nullptr, &buf, &bufType) == NERR_Success);

    // Safe RAII wrapper around NetApiBufferFree()
    auto deleter = [](void* ptr) { ::NetApiBufferFree(ptr); };
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(deleter)> autoDelete(buf, deleter);

    return std::wstring(buf);

// NetApiBufferFree() *automatically* invoked at function exit
}
```

Comment: You don't need a lambda for the `deleter`, you can pass `NetApiBufferFree()` directly to `std::unique_ptr`, as shown in my answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I read your answer after writing my code, but I honestly don't like repeating twice `&::NetApiBufferFree` like you did; I also think defining a lambda scales up better for longer deleter code, and when the deleter code changes I can change it only in one place.

Comment: if you don't want to duplicate specifying `&NetApiBufferFree` twice, that is easy enough to remedy - just use a variable: `auto deleter = ::NetApiBufferFree; std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(deleter)> autoDelete(buf, deleter);`